# Getting issue with Jenkins running as container, when executing Docker command for build images

Tags: docker, jenkins, devops, jenkins-docker

***Jenkins Docker Problem***

Hello Everyone,

I installed DockerTool on Windows7. And running Jenkins in container(http://192.168.99.100:8080), and try build image via freestyle project for a POC. Seems my Jenkins is not able to execute docker command, but getting below error on build : -
"***/tmp/jenkins4044405517350577133.sh: 2: /tmp/jenkins4044405517350577133.sh: docker: not found***"

I have configured, Docker as Cloud in Jenkins->Configuration, but '**Docker Host URI**' as tcp://192.168.99.100:2376 is not being connected, and keep running infinitely.

This value (tcp://192.168.99.100:2376), I get from executing command (docker-machine env) for **DOCKER_HOST** key.
[command output docker-machine env](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oucB4.jpg)

Please help me out!!!

Comment: Welcome to S.O!  Could you share your free style project configuration? In another way, create a new free style project and in build section, choose shell and put this : docker -v. Build and share us the result log.

Comment: Thanks Richard, any way this issue is resolved. I simply  install docker client on Jenkins...and it start working smoothly!!!